# How to Retrive Data from Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing my first android application and I'm having some difficulties understanding why the TextView "recipeContent" and "timeContent" are not being updated with the fields fetched from CloudFirestore.

I am using the following scripts.

CreateFragment.java:

```
package com.example.quickrecipe;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreateFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageButton createButton;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<Recipe> list;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String email = currentUser.getEmail();
    String usernameEmail = email.split("@")[0];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);
        createButton = view.findViewById(R.id.createButton);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recipesList);
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Query query = firestore.collection(usernameEmail+"MyRecipes");
        query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange dc : snapshot.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    switch (dc.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Recipe recipe = dc.getDocument().toObject(Recipe.class);
                            list.add(recipe);
                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:
                            Recipe modifiedRecipe = dc.getDocument().toObject(Recipe.class);
                            int modifiedIndex = getRecipeIndex(dc.getDocument().getId());
                            list.set(modifiedIndex, modifiedRecipe);
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:
                            int removedIndex = getRecipeIndex(dc.getDocument().getId());
                            list.remove(removedIndex);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private int getRecipeIndex(String recipeId) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Recipe recipe = list.get(i);
            if (recipe.getId().equals(recipeId)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateRecipe.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Animatoo.INSTANCE.animateSlideLeft(getActivity());
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.quickrecipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Recipe> mRecipes;
    private Context mContext;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String email = currentUser.getEmail();
    String usernameEmail = email.split("@")[0];

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipe> recipes) {
        mContext = context;
        mRecipes = recipes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Recipe recipe = mRecipes.get(position);

        // Connect to Cloud Firestore and fetch recipe content and time content
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection(usernameEmail+"MyRecipes")
                .whereEqualTo("RecipeName", recipe.getRecipeName())
                .whereEqualTo("Time", recipe.getTimeContent())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                String recipeContent = document.getString("RecipeName");
                                String timeContent = document.getString("Time");
                                holder.recipeContent.setText(recipeContent);
                                holder.timeContent.setText(timeContent);
                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.recipeContent.setText("Error loading recipe content");
                            holder.timeContent.setText("Error loading time content");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecipes.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView recipeContent;
        public TextView timeContent;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recipeContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeContent);
            timeContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase looks like this:

[firebase_rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Wds.png)
[firebase_fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rooF5.png)

Do you know why this is happening?

I've already tried to redo the connection with Firebase, but the TextView data continues to be replaced by null/empty.

Comment: There is *way* too much code here for us to efficiently help. While you may of course always get lucky and somebody may answer, chances of that drastically go up if you take the time to create a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem from scratch.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, to make it easier I tried to generate new classes with only the Cloud Firestore connection parts.

Answer (score 1):

the error was caused by the Case Sensitive in connection with firebase.